# Can we query the Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed just like the Cosmos DB Collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The documentation for Cosmos DB Change Feed mentions that the documents in Change Feed are persisted and can be processed asynchronously. The CreateDocumentFeedQuery has below prototype:

```
CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery(Uri collectionLink, ChangeFeedOptions feedOptions);
```

So the control offered is only on the level of ChangeFeedOptions where we can specify partition key range and the start time after which we need documents.

Is there any way we can query the Change Feed by passing in a custom query as done against the Cosmos DB Collection? Like querying based on document properties?

Answer (score 3):

Right now filtering the Change Feed by a query is not supported, like you said, you can filter by `PartitionKeyRangeId` and use the `ContinuationToken` to iterate over the feed.

[Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/20244082-support-filters-queries-on-the-change-feed) is the UserVoice item that tracks this request with an alternative using Spark.

Comment: The link is broken, the only reference I find is this link
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/03bb74ec-0e25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858?page=1